# Delete a user-defined TextPad document class?

Tags: textpad

How do you delete a user-defined TextPad document class?

The TextPad user manual and help only describe how to create a document class.

Answer (score 1):

Close all documents.

Go to Preferences -> Document Classes.

In the "User defined classes" list, click on the document class then click on the "X" symbol below the list.

Comment: Warning   You must click directly on Document Classes to display the red X delete button. Clicking the right-angle symbol (">") next to Document Classes only expands the Document Classes tree and does not display the red X delete button.